# При смене порта ssh после перезагрузки умирает сервер

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, администрирование

Итак, имеем абсолютно чистую систему centos 7.
И решил я перво-наперво там изменить порт ssh и сделать, например, 34567

Через winscp открываю файл /etc/ssh/sshd_config и вместо #Port 22 прописываю там

```
Port 22
Port 34567
```

В консоли вбиваю последовательно:

```
systemctl reload sshd
systemctl restart sshd
```

Затем открываю файл /etc/sysconfig/iptables и добавляю туда строку -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 34567 -j ACCEPT , т.е. привожу его к виду:

```
# sample configuration for iptables service
# you can edit this manually or use system-config-firewall
# please do not ask us to add additional ports/services to this default configuration
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 34567 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

сохраняю его, затем в консоли вбиваю последовательно:

```
systemctl reload iptables
systemctl restart iptables
```

После чего открываю новую копию winscp и пытаюсь подключиться к серверу по новому порту 34567 - все отлично соединяется! По 22 тоже все ОК

Результаты вывода команд:

```
# systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2016-03-11 16:45:15 EST; 5min ago
  Process: 543 ExecStop=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 529 ExecReload=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 605 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 605 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 11 16:45:15 gestiondbi-nl systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 firewall with iptables...
Mar 11 16:45:15 gestiondbi-nl iptables.init[605]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: [  OK  ]
Mar 11 16:45:15 gestiondbi-nl systemd[1]: Started IPv4 firewall with iptable
```

s.

```
    # systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2016-03-11 16:40:41 EST; 10min ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
  Process: 503 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 509 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─509 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Mar 11 16:40:41 gestiondbi-nl systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Mar 11 16:40:41 gestiondbi-nl systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Mar 11 16:40:41 gestiondbi-nl sshd[509]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 34567.
Mar 11 16:40:41 gestiondbi-nl sshd[509]: Server listening on :: port 34567.
Mar 11 16:40:41 gestiondbi-nl sshd[509]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 11 16:40:41 gestiondbi-nl sshd[509]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 11 16:48:27 gestiondbi-nl sshd[623]: Accepted password for root from xxx.xxx.205.136 port 63648 ssh2
Mar 11 16:48:39 gestiondbi-nl sshd[631]: Accepted password for root from xxx.xxx.205.136 port 63649 ssh2
Mar 11 16:48:51 gestiondbi-nl sshd[639]: Accepted password for root from xxx.xxx.205.136 port 63650 ssh2
Mar 11 16:49:37 gestiondbi-nl sshd[647]: Accepted password for root from xxx.xxx.205.136 port 30621 ssh2

# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:dhanalakshmi
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Вроде бы всё ок, можно перезагрузить сервер, делаю reboot и все, сервер умер и больше уже не подаёт признаков жизни - ни по 22 ни по 34567 порту к нему подключится уже не получается, в панели хостера у него также меняется статус на offline. Помогает только переустановка ОС. Сегодня пару раз проделывал эту операцию и неизменно после ребута она заканчивалась провалом.

В чем тут может быть причина? Помню раньше на других своих серверах менял порт ssh и все нормально было, они и сейчас работают на нестандартном порту. А тут взял у нового хостера несколько VPSок и вот.

Comment: Может нет возможности управления ядром ОСи и команда sysctl при этом срабатывает только для текущего сеанса?

Comment: но тогда по идее должна была остаться возможность подключаться по порту 22, я специально оставил такую возможность в конфигах. И на другом точно таком же впс настроил openvpn и после ребута там все нормально работает

Comment: если техподдержка хостинга не может ответить на вопрос «почему у вас такое происходит?», попробуйте сами определить, что именно приводит к неработоспособности: то ли добавление порта в конфигурацию *sshd*, то ли добавления правила в *netfilter*, то ли их комбинация: внесите одно из изменений и перезагрузите систему. если перезагрузится, переустановите систему, внесите второе из изменний и перезагрузите. // сакраментальный вопрос: а вы пробовали перезагружать систему **до** внесения изменений?

Comment: В ТП обращались? Наверняка ВПС на OpenVZ, отсюда и проблемы.

Answer (score 2):

У меня Debian 8. Имел аналогичную проблему.

решил следующим образом:
в файле

```
/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket
```

закомментировал

```
#[Socket]
#ListenStream=22
#Accept=yes
```

перезагрузил и все заработало
причину не выяснял и пока не разбирался что и как

Answer (score 1):

Доброго дня! Следует использовать пошаговую технологию.
1. просто перезагрузить сервер пару раз, для проверки;
2. изменить порт sshd и перезагрузиться снова. Теперь, если все работает
3. вносить правило в файерволл и опять перезагрузиться.
Таким путем Вы точно установите на каком этапе проблема.

Answer (score 0):

SElinux отключи и будет тебе счастье!